# Collapse Toolbar layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

i want to implement like Collapse Toolbar layout in android. But i don't understand in the xml how i use it. (I try to implement in this xml but its not work at this time this xml code not work properly tab in the top but still image show in the background).i want to implement this design but in Collapse Toolbar layout  [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="40dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.ImageSliderActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBack"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favoriteImage"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/heart"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shareImage"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/share"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/favoriteImage"
        />

</RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/heart"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_camera"

            />
        <com.ISHC.PathologyApp.Others.TextViewMedium
            android:id="@+id/imageCountTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewPager"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/pathoTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/maincolor"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/whiteColor"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/blackColor"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance">
           </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
         />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage3"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage4"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage5"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage6"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage7"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage8"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage9"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImage10"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/holo_circle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardDetailLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="@color/whiteColor">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.ISHC.PathologyApp.Others.TextViewMedium
                android:id="@+id/cardAmountTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text= "@string/cartTotal"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <com.ISHC.PathologyApp.Others.TextViewMedium
                android:id="@+id/cardSaveAmountTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="      You save: \u20B9 800"
                android:textColor="@color/maincolor"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Book"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@color/maincolor"
            android:text="Book Now"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor" />
    </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your challenge is Collapsing Toolbar Layout then feel free to check a solution I posted on github
https://github.com/mbobiosio/CoordinatorLayoutDemo

But if your challenge is TabLayouts then you're not doing the right thing from your layout.